# I need my applescript to run ONLY if Chrome is in focus

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

I am triggering an AppleScript with a keyboard shortcut. Works great. But I need the script to run ONLY if Google Chrome is currently in focus. All of the possibly relevant examples I've found are very complex (at least for me) and don't really do what I need.  Is there a simple "if" syntax I can use? If not, what's the simplest solution? Here's what I have:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    delete tab (active tab index of window 1) of window 1
end tell

tell application "Mail"
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every application has a `frontmost` property

```
if application "Google Chrome" is frontmost then
    tell application "Google Chrome" to delete tab (active tab index of window 1) of window 1
    activate application "Mail"
end if
```